# New XML File Listener

Tags: xml, listener

Current situation: We use a small site builder to build ecommerce sites specifically for web to print products. When an order is placed the site builder service exports a new XML file to specified directory which is then read by out management software to automatically generate a work order based off of the specs in the XML file.

Original Problem: Both the site builder we use and our management software are made by very small companies. They're customization is very limited and we haven't been able to get the XML to export/input 100% the way we need it to.

Solution: I've been learning as I go and wrote a new XSL file to restructure the data from the site builder software and style it so it should satisfy our management software appropriately and create the work orders we're looking for.

Current Dilemma: I need to setup an intermediate server with a listener to listen for new XML files (new orders) dropped into a specific directory, run it though my XSL file, and then export the new XML file to our management software's listener server.

I'm having trouble figuring out where to start with my research to make that happen. Can anyone help point me in the right direction based on what I've shared above? I'm not asking anyone to write it for me, but if you're able to suggest any services that would do this, or even words I should be using in my queries to find what I need I'd greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: The server this is going on is running Linux.

Comment: What OS?  For Windows, there is the FileSystemWatcher -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/october/windows-service-create-a-customizable-filesystemwatcher-windows-service

Comment: Using c# in windows you can use a controller.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @JayBuckman the server is running Linux.